# Azure AD Auth on LocalDB

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, localdb

I presume that LocalDB does not support Azure AD auth, as I receive the following error message:

```
CREATE USER [myuser] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

> Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER'.

(I'm attempting to create a Local DB for integration testing from the same DacPac).

However I cannot find any documentation that suggests explicitly that LocalDB (nor SQL Express) does not support Azure AD Auth.

Experience has found that just because it's not documented doesn't mean it's not possible.

In Azure SQL Server, you activate AD auth by assigning an Azure AD user to be an administrator, which can be done via AzureRM powershell module. Is there an equivalent none azurerm  way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Did this ever become available Alex? I am trying to do the same...

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft nice to bump into you :-) Afraid not. SQL/AAD was largely undocumented voodoo, but it has had some attention recently, so there is hope!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-service-principal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-only-authentication

local db is still on 2019 :-( so I suspect not yet. I'd suggest SQL in docker, which work nice in build agents and customise https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows-developer/dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is both not documented and not possible to do AAD auth on LocalDB.

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer Conor.